# Regex for italic markdown

Tags: java, regex, italic

I'm trying for hours with regex: I need a regex to select all that is inside underlines.
Example:

```
\_italic\_
```

But with the only condition that I need it to ignore `\\_` (backslash followed by underscore).

So, this would be a match (all the text which is inside the `\_`):

```
\_italic some text 123 \\_*%&$ _
```

SO far I have this regex:

```
(\_.*?\_)(?!\\\_)
```

But is not ignoring the `\\_`

Which regex would work?

Comment: Would you ever have a string like `\_test_test_`? or `_hola_hola__test_`

Comment: Really? It doesn't [look](https://regex101.com/r/tCQwzt/1) like it. Or can it *start* matching at an underscore even thought it's preceded by a forward slash?

Comment: You are right, it has that problem, no it cannot match.

Comment: And what would you like to match when you have a string like `_hola_hola_test_` and `_hola_hola__test_`?

Comment: In the first example hola_hola_test: first match: _hola_, second match: _test_

Comment: In the second example (_hola_hola__test_): first match: _hola_, second match: __

Comment: I don't quite get the results in the second example. Why should `__` be the 2nd match?

Comment: Because this is already not in the current question scope. The current question is about matching from a `_`, then any chars other than `_` or `\_`, up to the first `_`. I added `(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*` to the regex in the answer to make sure matching starts with an unescaped `_`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```java
(?s)(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*_((?:[^\\_]|\\.)+)_
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0LHAP8/2). *Details*:

- `(?s)` - an inline embedded flag option equal to `Pattern.DOTALL`
- `(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*` - a position that is not immediately preceded with a backslash and then zero or more sequences of double backslashes
- `_` - an underscore
- `((?:[^\\_]|\\.)+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more occurrences of any char other than a `\` and `_`, or any escaped char (a combination of a `\` and any one char)
- `_` - an underscore

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/UgMhVY):

```java
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("xxx _italic some text 123 \\_*%&$ _ xxx",
                                          "\\_test_test_");
String regex = "(?s)(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\{2})*_((?:[^\\\\_]|\\\\.)+)_";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
for (String str : strs) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    while(m.find()) {
        result.add(m.group(1));
    }
    System.out.println(str + " => " + String.join(", ", result));
}
```

Output:

```
xxx _italic some text 123 \_*%&$ _ xxx => italic some text 123 \_*%&$ 
\_test_test_ => test
```

Comment: This works perfectly, I really appreciate your time! Thanks, I'll learn more about non capturing groups.

Comment: Btw I copied and pasted the regex from the demo, the Java regex seems like it has problems. I pasted the original and intelij automatically adds the \ needed.

Comment: Ups, one little problem as JvdV stated: this text: \\_test_test_ won´t work with this regex

Comment: @Developer01561315 Use `(?s)(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*_((?:[^\\_]|\\.)+)_`. Copy/pasting strings to string literals is always prone to issues, make sure you know how to represent *literal strings* used on sheets of paper or online regex testers inside *string literals* used in code.

Comment: Thanks, it seems it solves the problem, Ill try more cases, thank you!!!